# LSP config ttserver suggests the same completions

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I faced with problem that ttserver in LSP config suggests me certain the same suggestions depended on different servers. Here is an example below
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K31A.png) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K31A.png

Here is my lsp config too
[lsp-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ig5j.png) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ig5j.png

Comment: Please post the code as a text not an image.

Comment: I got the following message "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223304/need-at-least-10-reputation-to-post-an-image-please-explain

Comment: i'm stuck with it